# Determining whether given sets are compact, and providing justification for when they aren't

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, compactness

Problem 3.3.2 in `Understanding Analysis` by Stephen Abott.

I'd like someone to verify if my work checks out and my proof makes sense.

> Decide which of the following sets are compact. For those that are not compact, show how the definition of compactness breaks down. In other words, give an example of a sequence contained in the given set that does not possess a subsequence converging to a limit in the set.

(a) $\mathbf{N}$

(b) $\mathbf{Q} \cap [0,1]$

(c) The Cantor Set.

(d) $\{1 + 1/2^2 + 1/3^2 + \ldots + 1/n^2: n \in \mathbf{N}\}$

(e) $\{1,1/2,2/3,3/4,4/5,\ldots\}$

***My Attempt.***

(a) $\mathbf{N}$ is not compact.

Consider the sequence $(a_n)$, $a_n:=n$. Any proper subsequence of $(a_n)$ does not converge to a limit in $\mathbf{N}$. Moreover, $\mathbf{N}$ is unbounded.

(b) $\mathbf{Q} \cap [0,1]$ is not compact.

Consider the sequence of partial sums $(s_m)$ where,

\begin{align*}
s_m = \sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{(-1)^{(n-1)}}{(n-1)!}
\end{align*}

The first few terms of the sequence are
\begin{align*}
s_1 &= 1\\
s_2 &= 1 - \frac{1}{1!}\\
s_3 &= 1 - \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!}\\
s_4 &= 1 - \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!}\\
s_5 &= 1 - \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!} + \frac{1}{4!}
\end{align*}

It is an easy exercise to prove that $s_k \in \mathbf{Q} \cap [0,1]$ for all $k$. And, we know that this is the Taylor's polynomial for $e^{-1}$. Any subsequence of $(s_n)$ would also converge to the same limit. $1/e$ is not in $\mathbf{Q} \cap [0,1]$. So, it is not a compact set.

(c) The Cantor set is closed, since it is the complement of an countably infinite union of open intervals. The countably infinite union of open intervals is an open set, so its complement is closed. Moreover, the Cantor set is contained in $[0,1]$ so it is closed and bounded. Hence, it is compact.

(d) From general mathematics reading, I think that this infinite series converges to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, so the limit value is not in the set, and hence it's not compact.

More rigorously, my approach is as follows.

Assume that $K$ is compact.

First, it is easy to show that $1 < s_k \le 2$  for all $k \in \mathbf{N}$. And it is a monotonically increasing sequence, so by the monotone convergence theorem, this infinite series converges to a limit say $l$, $1 < l \le 2$.

Construct an open interval $O_k$ around each point $s_k \in K$ of radius $\lvert s_k - l \rvert/2$. Then, $\{O_k:k \in \mathbf{N}\}$ is an open cover for $K$. If we assume that $K$ is compact, then there exists a finite subcover that contains $K$. There exists $n_0$ such that,

\begin{align*}
\bigcup_{k=1}^{n_0} O_k \supset K
\end{align*}

We want to produce a point in $K$, that is the sequence $(s_k)$, which is not an element of the finite subcover. Fix

\begin{align*}
\epsilon_0 = \frac{\lvert {s_{n_0} - l} \rvert }{2}
\end{align*}

Since, $(s_k)$ converges to $l$, there exists $s_N$ such that $\lvert{s_N - l}\rvert < \epsilon_0$. But, the finite subcover $\{O_1,O_2,\ldots,O_{n_0}\}$ does contain the point $s_N$. This is a contradiction. We conclude, that our initial assumption is false and $K$ is not compact.

(e) This set is bounded. It's limit point is $1$, which is contained in the set, so it is closed. Hence, it is a compact set.

Comment: They all seem correct to me. Maybe for $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ you can say that is not closed and hence not compact (You are working on a Hausdorff space).

Comment: In your proof for (d) you need to justify that $l \ne s_n$ for any $n$. Otherwise one of your "open neighborhoods" would be empty, and the corresponding $s_n$ would not be covered. (It's an easy fix - $s_n$ is strictly increasing.)  For (b), I suspect you are okay, but your argument depends on knowing that $1/e$ is irrational, which is not an easy proof. You might want to switch to rational approximations of a number more easily seen to be irrational, such as $1/\sqrt 2$ or $0.1101001000100001...$